# What is an undergraduate student?

Tags: vocabulary, academic-latin

What would be a good way to say "undergraduate student" in Latin?
The exact meaning depends on context: in Finland I would use that to refer to a student without a master's degree even if they have a bachelor's, but in the US I would mean a student without a bachelor's.

There is no reason to try to translate the term literally.
The Finnish term would translate to English as "basic degree student".
I am not sure how to describe such students in Latin.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Two options. First, there is *alumnus*. For example, [this text](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433081641171;view=1up;seq=76) describes the life of Johannes Franciscus Du De Loz, in stages, from birth to death, including being an student of theology (presumably undergraduate), then a lector, professor, rector, and so on. There are several other examples in the text.

A second option is *scholare gradus baccalaureatus*, inspired from bottom paragraph [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044079835245;view=1up;seq=54), and turned (maybe unsuccessfully) into genitive. Notice that *scholares* is in direct opposition to *alumni* (notice use of _sive, e.g. in page following that linked above). This expression would apply to any who is studying for a bachelor's degree, regardless of any previous status (e.g. graduate from another degree). This is, in my view more precise, as an undergraduate would be that who is pursuing "undergraduate" studies, instead of "graduate" studies. The latter is a common terminology nowadays, in my opinion.

(the second link provided are the regulations of the University of Oxford, from early 19th century. Maybe you can find a better expression there than I could.)