# What is "parecbolae"?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, new-latin, synonyms

Researching an answer for [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/what-is-an-undegraduate-student), I found a book of regulations of the University of Oxford, dating from the early 19th century. The title is:

[image]

I cannot find the meaning of *Parecbolae* anywhere. L&S [returns nothing](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&all_words=parecbolae&phrase=&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=). If you google that word, all you get are links to precisely that book! (which, being regulations of a university, was republished over many subsequent years).

I have no clue what it could mean, since clearly it's unrelated to *[parabola](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parabola#Latin)*.

Comment: FWIW, 1) googling _parecbola_ gives tens of _excerpta_ & _oxonienses_. But I found this [XVII century book](https://books.google.cl/books?id=v00tKoGFI88C&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=parecbola+-%22sive+excerpta%22&source=bl&ots=TVtm8H3JOg&sig=J78d9LaOsCVJgrPyzCpycH8nZkM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi519_A14rcAhXBHZAKHceaBNUQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=parecbola%20-%22sive%20excerpta%22&f=false) with 3 occurrences, 2) L&S lists [parectatus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dparectatus) as a Greek borrowing. Both parec- and -bola seem like Greek roots to me.

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, it looked like *para-* with a mutated vowel but it's really an ellided *para-* + *ek-* (Gr. for *ex-*) + *bolē* (Gr. for *bola*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a word transliterated and adapted from Greek παρεκβολή (*parekbolḗ*), from [πᾰρά](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=para%2f&filter=CUTF8) (*para-*, "near", but here meaning "placed together") and [ἐκβολή](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=e%29kbolh%2f&filter=CUTF8) (*ekbolḗ*, "throwing out" but here meaning "something tossed off"), which together can be a "compilation of a set of critical remarks":

> **παρεκβολή**, ἡ,
>   I. *digression*, lamb.Bab.8.
>   II. *compilation of a set of critical remarks*, as those of Eust. on
>   Homer, Pindar, and Dionysius Periegeta, cf. eund. ad D.P.426;
>   παρεκβολαὶ διαφόρων γραμματικῶν, title of Sch.D.T. in
>   Cod.BMus.Add.5118.
>   — [Liddell, Scott, Jones](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=parekbolh%2F&filter=CUTF8)

As the word *sive* ("or", "or also", "also called") indicates as well, the plural *parecbolae* is used here as a synonym of *excerpta*. The author names his work *parecbolae*, to which he adds *excerpta* as an explanation or translation for those who might not know the word *parecbola*.

It might be a fairly late adaptation, for I couldn't find any classical Latin sources. *Parécbole* is in a Portuguese dictionary: https://www.dicio.com.br/parecbole/ It's also used in a few other languages, amongst which English, but very rarely (Google [search results](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22parecbole%7Cparecboles%7Cparecbola%7Cparecbolae%22%20-excerpta&nfpr=1)). There is mention of a Parecbole by [Eustathius of Thessalonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustathius_of_Thessalonica) (a major Byzantine scholar), then the book from the question, and also a gloss describing the meaning of the word in general, through referring to the work by Eustathius. References to parecbolae on/from Aristotle by [Theodorus Metochites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Metochites) (another major Byzantine scholar) can be found as well. Then there are a few more results (in addition, no doubt, to other uses of the word outside Google's limited reach).

Comment: Amazing! So who made the adaptation? Was it a relatively recent adaptation, given that it seems it did not exist in Classical Latin?

Comment: @luchonacho: I have no idea, but it might be a fairly late adaptation, since we couldn't find any classical Latin sources. *Parécbole* is in a Portuguese dictionary: https://www.dicio.com.br/parecbole/ It's also used in a few other languages, amongst which English, but very rarely: https://www.google.com/search?q=parecbole+-excerpta&client=firefox-b&nfpr=1&filter=0&biw=1080&bih=1701

Comment: Not really rarely: all those uses seem to *just* be mentions of this particular book, making it less than a nonceword. The English cognate seems to be *parecbasis* & co.

Comment: @lly: Not quite: there is mention of a Parecbole by one Eustathius of Thessalonica, then the book from the question, and also a gloss describing the meaning of the word in general, through referring to the work by Eustathius. References to parecbolae on Aristotle by one Theodorus Metochita(s?) can be found as well, if you expand the search a little bit: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22parecbole%7Cparecboles%7Cparecbola%7Cparecbolae%22+-excerpta&nfpr=1 Then there are a few more results (in addition, no doubt, to other uses of the word outside Google's limited reach).

Comment: @lly: P.S. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Pains me to see major Byzantine scholars peppered with "one" and "(?)" :-) . So: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustathius_of_Thessalonica (the major Byzantine commentator on Homer), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Metochites

Comment: @NickNicholas: Sorry! I'm ashamed to admit I know far too little about Byzantine literature (it was somehow never in the curriculum at uni). I was going to look up more information about them but I forgot. I've added your references to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a clue in the *sive* which separates the word from *excerpta*.

*Sive* was once customarily used to mean 'or' when giving an explanatory sub-title to a more obscure name. For example, the well-known *Gradus*, popular in various editions and more or less contemporary with your Oxford University example, had the full title *Gradus ad Parnassum, sive synonymorum et epithetorum thesaurus*.

I deduce that *parecbolae* is just another word for *excerpta*. It would not necessarily be classical.

[On a point of information, Fellows of OU had at that time to be in holy orders of the Church of England, and must therefore swear to adhere to the Thirty-Nine Articles of religion referred to.]

Comment: Does it have a meaning in Greek, perhaps?

Comment: @Rafael A Greek origin sounds likely enough, but I have really no idea.